# Passing a struct to a function like this

Tags: c, function, struct

I have a question about passing a struct to a function without declaring the struct first.

I have a function that takes a struct pointer like this:

```
static void DrawArc(struct MATH_POINT *p, other args);
```

I know I can pass a structure like this

```
struct MATH_POINT point = {0,0};
DrawArc(&point, other args);
```

But I can also do it like this:

```
DrawArc(&(struct MATH_POINT){0,0}, other args);
```

I am doing it this way because I am on an embedded platform with very limited register space, and my GUI functions require many arguments.

But my worry is that the structures I initialized in the argument list will stick around and use up RAM. Is this possible? Or will the struct be destroyed as soon as the function finishes?

Thanks!

Comment: This question cannot be answered without knowing the specific compiler and processor you are using.  Also, whether or not you will build with optimization enabled.

Comment: I am using arm-none-eabi and I have -O2 I am using STM32F767-144 pin.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing and matching things. Any object which is not explicitly instantiated with `malloc`/`calloc`/etc but it is instantiated locally won't take any heap memory, it will just make the stack grow until the variable exits the scope.

Your first example:

```
struct MATH_POINT point = {0,0};
DrawArc(&point, other args);
```

is perfectly fine. `point` will be allocated on stack, it won't take more memory than the one needed to store itself and it will be automatically released upon exiting the scope of declaration.

In any case, in both your examples, since there is no dynamic allocation, there's no risk of leaving things around.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I'll test code size of the two methods too. And I think I'll stick with the first method and keep the point variable around for future use.

Answer (score -1):

```
struct MATH_POINT point = {0,0};
DrawArc(&point, other args);
```

this point variable will live longer than this

```
DrawArc(&(struct MATH_POINT){0,0}, other args);
```

since the first one's scope is still alive after calling DrawArc, while the second is discarded as soon as the function returns. (and: Neither of them "stick around", both have a well defined lifecycle ;-) )

if you want to "remove" a variable, add an additional scope, and close it if you don't need it anymore:

```
#define MANY 10000
{ 
    struct MATH_POINT removeMe[MANY];
    /* work on removeMe while they're alive */
    doThings(removeMe, other_stuff);
} 
/* here removeMe is gone, and the mem can/will be used otherwise */
```

Comment: `while the second is discarded as soon as the function returns. ` No. A function doesn't introduce or end a scope. The compound literal's lifetime lasts until a closing bracket in the current block (The one the function call is in).

Comment: erm ... and when exactly are the function parameters (in case they're temporary for this call) going out of scope? As soon as the function returns. I didnt say there's a new scope introduced ?!?

Comment: I was arguing against your quote, which is not correct.

Comment: it's created on the stack, and freed with the ret of the function called. what's wrong ?? answer please. "see first comment" doesnt

Comment: That statement is not correct. See the first comment.

Comment: Keep comments civil please.